# Internet connection blocked

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, internet

I am using chrome and firefox. When I open webpages, It is showing

```
Google Chrome's connection attempt to superuser.com was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.
```

Google sites are working but other than that nothing is working.

Edge is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue. I did so many things

```
ipv4 settings
Find some unwanted softwares
```

But nothing is working.

Finally. I got one tool from chrome. `Chrome Cleanup Tool`  It have found one addon called smartBar. I removed this one and it is working fine